# Cannot create SQL RDS native backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create RDS database backup to s3 backup using native backup:

```
 exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
 @source_db_name='db_name',
 @s3_arn_to_backup_to='my_s3_arn/db_name.bak',
 @overwrite_s3_backup_file=1;
```

After executing, I get this error from task status info:

```
Task execution has started. Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup.
Task has been aborted The provided token has expired.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error info is saying that your token has expired. This is the token of the role which is used to create native backups(SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option). This shouldn't happen normally.

Try these options and after each one check if you can create the native backup:

- Reboot your database instance
- Stop/Start your database instance
- Recreate the option for the native backups
- Recreate the entire option group

The last option is the one that fixed the problem when I tested revoking the role sessions.

Comment: I have recreated the option for the native backups and the problem is solved for me, Thank you.